# Modify The corresponding built In functions of queue or stack provided in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

Can we modify for eg enqeue function only in c++ of queue and use the rest defined as in queue library provided by c++.

For eg- I include queue in my cpp file and modify the corresponding enqueue function and use the rest dequeu, front, pop etc. as it is as defined in the library itself

Comment: std containers are not designed to be subclassed.

Comment: [*XY problem*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @didierc- there was a question for a level  order traversal which would take either take double the space needed from conventional methods or many comparisons but modifying enqueue operation it would take only o(logn) space and I needed to modify only the enqueue operation so I thought if its possible to use STL containers itself by subclassing them and modifying the required function